# Set n decimal places in BigDecimal and format the number Java

Tags: java

I am currently using the BigDecimal and with variable number of digits after decimal point. I need to be able to format the number with loosing the number of digits which I had set, because when I use format then it reduces the decimal digits to 2 - 4.

```
str1 =bigDecimal.setScale(numberOfDecimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

str2 = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(bigDecimal.setScale(numberOfDecimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

The first list works fine but when I want to format the String/BigDecimal then it drops the decimal places.

Note: Decimal place will vary from 0 to 15(from user). I am using Android Studio-API15/Java. Precision is important in my app, formatting is to improve readability.

Comment: You need to change the NumberFormat, not the BigDecimal. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-

Comment: Please, could you add and example on correct input/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @JB Nizet, you need to tune NumberFormat acc. to your need.

Below is a working example:

```
int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 6;

BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(11212.122323);
bigDecimal.setScale(numberOfDecimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(numberOfDecimalPlaces);

System.out.println(numberFormat.format(bigDecimal));
```

Output:

```
11,212.122323
```